# HTML, Disable markup process

Tags: javascript, html

I try to find a way to disable the following scenario:

```
<div>
     <span>
</div>
```

Html will autocomplete the missing `</span>`, Is there a way?, Maybe a tag?, Anything to disable this behavior inside the `<div>` tag?

Is there a way to disable this behavior via javascript?

Comment: Why do you want to disable this behavior?

Comment: I'm working on code highlighter project, I don't want html to autocomplete missing tags.

Comment: Do you want to display the tag as text?

Comment: If this "feature" is off, the page _should_ break because it's no longer a valid HTML.

Comment: Is there no way to disable on what inside the div element?

Comment: @Chrisi I convert the tag into html entities.

Comment: @AvielFadida You might be asking an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Try to explain what you _actually_ want to do (in question, not in comment).

Comment: I still dont quite understand your question? As Passerby already said, HTML has to put the closing tag in order to substain valid markup. Do you read the HTML source code from a stream? Or is it an editor who adds a closing tag?

Comment: What does code highlighting have to do with the way the browser parses HTML? The code highlighter should be operating on the original source, not the rendered DOM.

Comment: @Barmar Is there a way to get the original source via javascript, Because until now i was working on the innerHTML.

Comment: HTML does not do anything. It is a data format. If you are asking how to change HTML parsers in a browser, the answer is “by rewriting part of the browser”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not that "HTML autocompletes the missing `</span>`". If your browser wouldn't do that, your page would be completely broken. What you really want to do is to tell the browser to stop parsing the page.

There is no way to disable parsing inside of an element. What you can use, though, are HTML escape characters. They tell the browser that you want to display characters like `<` and `>` instead of using them as HTML code.

### HTML

- Replace `<` with `&lt;` (**l***ess* **t***han*)
- Replace `>` with `&gt;` (**g***reater* **t***han*)

#### Example

```
<div>
    &lt;span&gt;
</div>
```

You will see this in your browser:

```
<span>
```

### Javascript

If you have a *string* in Javascript that contains HTML code that you want to display on your page, you can use `innerText` to insert it into an element. All characters will be replaced by their escaped versions, if necessary.

#### Example

```
var code = '<div class="mydiv">',
    outer = document.getElementById("outer");

outer.innerText = code;
```

Comment: Your solution will work but only on the source code not on the innerHTML, Is there a way i can get the source code?

Comment: @AvielFadida Are you inserting the code that you want to display with `element.innerHTML`?

Comment: @AvielFadida Use `innerText` instead. It will do the replacing for you.

Comment: I did try, The problem is what if i want to highlight html markup?

Comment: If you want to highlight code, then you have to parse the string yourself, replace the characters manually and add `<span>` elements around it. Example: `<span>` could become `&lt;<span class="tagname">span</span>&gt;`.